# JSON for column width in Modern SharePoint Online List is not working

Tags: json, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-list

I know the script is working as the text color changes and there are no errors; no matter what `width` I put in, however, it does not change. So if I put in 300, 600, or 1000, for example, it stays the same when viewed.

I have changed the column width to different values as I said above, and have changed from text to rich text, enhanced, etc.

```json
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "txtContent": "@currentField",
  "style": {
        "color": "green",
        "width": "300px"
  }
}
```

I would expect the column width to be the set size indicated in the script, e.g., 600, 300, 1000.

Comment: Did you find an answer to this?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the style name `column-width` and removing `px` from the width value. I needed to change the column width and, after reading about JSON, I still needed an example and found your question.  I changed the style name and the width value and was successful.

```json
{ 
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/column-formatting.schema.json", 
  "elmType": "div", 
  "txtContent": "@currentField", 
  "style": { 
    "color": "green",
    "column-width": "300" 
  }
}
```